# How to use leftJoinAndSelect query in TypeORM postgres?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I've been using TypeORM and made some Entities as follows:

- `User.ts`

  ```js
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number
  ```
- `Post.ts`

  ```js
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  userId: number
  ```

As I didn't want to make relations between `User` and `Post` entities, I just made a column named `userId` at `Post`.

**Here's the question.**

I'd like to join two tables and fetch data. But how can I use `innerJoinAndSelect` or `leftJoinAndSelect`?

Here's my code:

```js
// getPost.ts

// Attempt 1
const first = await createQueryBuilder()
  .select('user')
  .from(User, 'user')
  .leftJoinAndSelect(Post, 'post', 'post.userId = user.id')
  .getMany() // only fetched User data without Post data

// Attempt 2
const second = await createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('user.id', 'userId')
  .innerJoinAndMap('user.id', Post, 'post', 'userId = post.userId')
  .getMany() // Bad request error
```

But None of these worked...

I'd like to join `User` with `Post` and grab all data (but not using relation). How could I get these data?

Comment: Is this because you don't want to create foreign keys on the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`leftJoinAndMapOne` should work. But you’ve just omitted first argument `mapToProperty`.

Just fix your `getPost.ts` as this

```js
const first = await createQueryBuilder()
  .select(‘user’)
  .from(User, ‘user’)
  // ------------------------ fixed ------------------------
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(‘user.id’, Post, ‘post’, ‘post.userId = user.id’)
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  .getMany()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to create foreign key relations in the database, but still would like to use join operations on the entities, you can use `createForeignKeyConstraints` property in the relation options to achieve this.

Update your entities as below:

#### `User.ts`

```js
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number

@OneToMany(() => Post, (post) => post.user)
posts: Post[]
```

#### `Post.ts`

```js
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number

@Column()
userId: number

@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.posts, { createForeignKeyConstraints: false })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
user: User
```

Now you should be able to use `find` or `QueryBuilder` methods on these entities just as they had an actual relationship in the database.

---

I didn't test this code but this is the essence of what you should be doing. Hope this helps. Cheers  !!!